# Parsing Event Hub Complex Array Type messages using spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I need to parse the Array Type in body while reading from eventhub. we have nested json message but not able to parse the same:

{"Name": "Rohit","Salary": "29292","EmpID": 12,"Projects": [{"ProjectID": "9191","ProjectName": "abc","Duration": "79"},{"ProjectID": "9192","ProjectName": "xyz","Duration": "75"}]}

I am trying to modify the schema using below: but seems there is some issue.

```
val testSchema = new StructType()
  .add("Name", StringType)
  .add("Salary", StringType)
  .add("EmpID", StringType)      
  .add("Projects", new ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("ProjectID", StringType)
    .add("ProjectName", StringType)
    .add("Duration", StringType)))
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without exact error it's hard to say, but it looks like that you have an error in schema definition - you need to modify schema to add flag specifying if array elements could be nullable or not (see the `true` flag after nested StructType).  Following schema works fine when reading JSON directly or trasforming it from string:

```
val testSchema = new StructType()
  .add("Name", StringType)
  .add("Salary", StringType)
  .add("EmpID", StringType)      
  .add("Projects", new ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("ProjectID", StringType)
    .add("ProjectName", StringType)
    .add("Duration", StringType), true))

scala> spark.read.schema(testSchema).json("file.json").show(truncate=false)
+-----+------+-----+----------------------------------+
|Name |Salary|EmpID|Projects                          |
+-----+------+-----+----------------------------------+
|Rohit|29292 |12   |[{9191, abc, 79}, {9192, xyz, 75}]|
+-----+------+-----+----------------------------------+

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val df = spark.read.text("file.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> df.select(from_json($"value", testSchema)).show(truncate=false)
+------------------------------------------------------+
|from_json(value)                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|{Rohit, 29292, 12, [{9191, abc, 79}, {9192, xyz, 75}]}|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for very prompt answer, schema definition works.

Comment: I have further complexity where we need to do parse of nested array schema and then flatten it out to push in destination synapse DB.

{"Name": "Rohit","Salary": "29292","EmpID": 12,"Projects":[{"ProjectID": "9191", "ProjectName": "abc", "Duration": "79","Location" :[{"City" : "Delhi", "State" : "DEL"},{"City" : "BANG",  "State" : "KR" }]},{"ProjectID": "9192", "ProjectName": "xyz", "Duration": "75","Location" :[{"City" : "BANG", "State" : "KR"},{"City" : "CH", "State" : "TN" }]}]}

Can you advise of this ?

Comment: You can use explode function to convert array elements into individual rows

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am getting error while defining schema for nested array. Can you help to define the schema for nested array in above example

val testSchema = new StructType()
  .add("Name", StringType)
  .add("Salary", StringType)
  .add("EmpID", StringType)      
  .add("Projects", new ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("ProjectID", StringType)
    .add("ProjectName", StringType)
    .add("Duration", StringType), true)
  .add("Location", new ArrayType(new StructType()
   .add("City", StringType)
   .add("State", StringType), true)))

Comment: the problem is here: ` .add("Duration", StringType), true) .add("Location", new ArrayType(` - you need to move first `, true` before 2nd closing bracket at the end...

Comment: thanks @Alex for your inputs, I had one question regarding exploding multiple array of structs in DF. do we have to create 2 separate DFs and then join them. spark doesn't allow multiple explode in one select statement. advise ?

root
 |-- Name: 
 |-- Projects: struct 
 |    |-- ProjectID: 
 |    |-- ProjectName: 
 |    |-- Duration: 
 |    |-- Location: array
 |    |    |-- element: struct
 |    |    |    |-- City: 
 |    |    |    |-- State: 
 |    |-- Contact: array
 |    |    |-- element: struct 
 |    |    |    |-- Phone
 |    |    |    |-- email

Comment: just do select(explode).select(explode), etc. - Spark won't execute them anyway until you have action